# Angular 2: How to provide interpolation with [routerLink]

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routing defined in routing.ts file in this way.

```
const routesapp: Routes= [
{path:'user/id', component:UserComponent}
];
export const:routing ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routesapp, {useHash:true});
```

and in HTML

```
<li class ="Some class">
    <a href= "#/user/{{id}}"> Link </a>
</li>
```

How do I convert this to work with [routerLink]? From previous posts I learnt that we cannot add interpolation with [routerLink], i.e [routerLink] = ['user/{{id}}']

I want to add interpolation in HTML only and I cannot add it in routing file. Also, How to override useHash of routing file in HTML?

Comment: Have you tried `[routerLink] = "['/user/' + id]"`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this

```
<li class ="Some class">
    <a [routerLink]="['user', idVariable]">Link </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

This router link worked for me 
[routerLink]="['/edit', element.ID]"

I used it in the following:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" [routerLink]="['/edit', element.ID]" 
routerLinkActive="router-link-active" > {{ element.RequesterName }}</a>
```

Thanks!