# Angular2 - Navigating to single item

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How can I navigate to a single event from a list of events?

```
<md-card *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a href="" routerLinkActive="event/{{event.slug}}"><img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" />{{ event.name }}</a>
</md-card>
```

Comment: `<a [routerLink]="['event', event.slug]"`?

Comment: yes! thank you. please add an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to provide interpolation with \[routerLink\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104040/angular-2-how-to-provide-interpolation-with-routerlink)

Comment: Maybe not duplicated, but content is strongly related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in docs of [**`RouterLinkActive`**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive):

> The RouterLinkActive directive lets you add a CSS class to an element
>   when the link's route becomes active.

To navigate, you should use [**`RouterLink`**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink):

```
<a [routerLink]="['event', event.slug]"
```

or

```
<a routerLink="event/{{event.slug}}"
```

Comment: No, the second option isnt truly recommended. Avoid manual concatenation, just pass the values in the link parameters array and let angular do the rest.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo First, the 2nd. option, is just a copy from question (I just replaced​ `routerLinkActive` by `routerLink`). And I can't see any concatenation here (huh?)... Anyway, where did you find that *"isn't truly recommended..."*?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Also, if you downvoted it, please explain why my answer isn't correct. I'd love to learn with you.

Comment: Please take a look on the docs https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink
By concatenation I meant that in the 2nd approach static and dynamic parameters are being manually merged into a link. In the docs (description section) the only explained method to merge values is the one with the array. Using interpolation to merge values is not mentioned or suggested => not (explicitly) recommended by the documentation.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo dude, as I said, the 2nd. option was just copied from the question to show that he can keeps doing that way, the only thing needed was: replace `routerLinkActive` by `routerLink`. About the docs: so, are you saying that if something isn't mentioned it become automatically incorrect or as you keep saying: *"not truly recommended"*? To say that something isn't recommended or incorrect, you have to show some resource that **explicitly** says that "blabla" isn't recommended (and also explain why) to prove your afirmation, otherwise it's just fallacy.

Comment: Didnt said that it was incorrect, but yes, google around and you will notice that it isn't easy to find a site showing a use of router link with interpolation. I considered right to point that out, as your answer suggest something that is not standard. Again, nobody will say that is incorrect, but at the same time an experienced angular user wouldn't recommend that syntax. Angular is based in convention over configuration, so why would somebody not want to stick to the conventions/standards that are shown in the docs? :)

Comment: *"...find a site showing a use of router link with interpolation...*" Do you think it means something? Only this fact suggests that it's considered truly not recommended? *"...as your answer suggest something that is not standard...*" Who defined this standard? You? *", so why would somebody not want to stick to the conventions/standards that are shown in the docs?..."* It means that if something isn't in docs, I **must not** use or apply it in my project(s)? C'mon man, you can **only** convince me if you prove what you're saying, otherwise, **this is just your truth**.